# Can I measure the necessary buffer for sprintf in Microsoft C++?

Tags: c++, c, buffer, printf

I'm writing a small proof-of-concept console program with Visual Studio 2008 and I wanted it to output colored text for readability. For ease of coding I also wanted to make a quick printf-replacement, something where I could write like this:

```
MyPrintf(L"Some text \1[bright red]goes here\1[default]. %d", 21);
```

This will be useful because I also build and pass strings around in some places so my strings will be able to contain formatting info.

However I hit a wall against `wsprintf` because I can't find a function that would allow me to find out the required buffer size before passing it to the function. I could, of course, allocate 1MB just-to-be-sure, but that wouldn't be pretty and I'd rather leave that as a backup solution if I can't find a better way.

Also, alternatively I'm considering using `std::wstring` (I'm actually more of a C guy with little C++ experience so I find plain-old-char-arrays easier for now), but that doesn't have anything like `wsprintf` where you could build a string with values replaced in them.

So... what should I do?

Comment: This has been a known problem with `sprintf()` for a very long time.  That's why C99 added `snprintf()`.  While you can make guesses at the length of the string, determining it properly starts to require recreating most of the `printf()` functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [_snwprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93(VS.71).aspx). That function takes a buffer size, and if the buffer isn't big enough, just double the size of the buffer and try again. To keep from having to do multiple _snwprintf calls each time, keep track of what the buffer size was that you ended up using last time, and always start there. You'll make a few excess calls here and there, and you'll waste a bit of ram now and then, but it works great, and can't over-run anything.

Comment: In GCC there's a similar function called snprintf. Instead of using that or the one you suggest which is MS specific, it's better to use a portable replacement like this: http://www.ijs.si/software/snprintf/

Comment: As Manuel stated - it should be made clear that Microsoft's `_snprintf()` differs from the standard `snprintf()` in significant ways and should be avoided in preference to one that behaves in a more standard fashion if possible. Unfortunately, it looks like MS haven't fixed this problem in VS2010...  I prefer Holger Weiss' implementation since the license is very non-restrictive (I'm not sure how the Frontier Artistic license applies to my whole program if I incorporate  Mark Martinec's `snprintf()` from http://www.ijs.si into my program).

Comment: I wanted to give an answer that didn't require adding libraries, so I went with the solution local to the OP. I personally also prefer the standard snprintf because it's return value is much more useful, but I hate telling folks to drag in external libraries for one function.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is tagged C++, in which case I'd say std::wstringstream is the way to go.  Example:

```
#include <sstream>

void func()
{
    // ...

    std::wstringstream ss;  // the string stream

    // like cout, you can add strings and numbers by operator<<
    ss << L"Some text \1[bright red]goes here\1[default]. " << 21;

    // function takes a C-style const wchar_t* string
    some_c_function(ss.str().c_str()); // convert to std::wstring then const wchar_t*
    // note: lifetime of the returned pointer probably temporary
    // you may need a permanent std::wstring to return the c_str() from
    // if you need it for longer.

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for a C++ stringstream. It's not as compact as sprintf but it will give you the functionality you want.

Comment: Could you give some examples of usage? As I said, I'm not very strong in C++ and all those templates make my head spin. I can't really make out how it's supposed to work from the documentation. :(

Comment: AshleysBrain has provided an example which covers your post. I'll avoid duplicating his example.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford using boost, you could consider [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/format/index.html). It would give you the flexibility of `std::string`s, and formatting features of `sprintf`. It is fairly different from C-style, but is also fairly easy to use. Here's an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/format/example/sample_formats.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

[_scprintf, _scprintf_l, _scwprintf, _scwprintf_l](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32cf9tb.aspx)

This functions will return the number of characters in the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::wstring` seems like a good solution if you plan on passing strings between your objects - it handles the size and has a nice `c_str` method that will give you the array of wide chars.

The additional benefit is that you can pass it by reference instead of by pointer.

When you need the actuall string just use c_str method:

```
wprintf(L"string %s recieved!", myWString.c_str());
```

Comment: Fine, but what about when I want something like `"Opened connection to %s on port %hd"` ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an expansion of the answer from @mheyman that uses `vswprintf()`.

I also struggled with the same problem.  The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsprintf-vsprintf-l-vswprintf-vswprintf-l-vswprintf-l?view=msvc-170) is weak, but this page was helpful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfwprintf

CppRef Description: `If bufsz is greater than zero, writes the results to a wide string buffer. At most bufsz-1 wide characters are written followed by null wide character. If bufsz is zero, nothing is written (and buffer may be a null pointer).`

CppRef Return value: `Number of wide characters written (not counting the terminating null wide character) if successful or negative value if an encoding error occurred or if the number of characters to be generated was equal or greater than size (including when size is zero).`

Roughly:

1. Measure required buffer size by calling `vswprintf()` with `buffer == NULL` and `bufsz == 0`
2. Call `malloc()` (or friends) to allocate a buffer.
3. Again, call `vswprintf()` with allocated buffer and buffer size + 1
4. Use result
5. Call `free()` on allocated buffer

Your example uses `wchar_t`: `MyPrintf(L"Some text \1[bright red]goes here\1[default]. %d", 21);`, so I recommend something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // includes both <wchar.h> and <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // calloc()

void MyPrintf(const wchar_t *lpFormatWCharArr,
              ...)
{
    // Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/va-arg-va-copy-va-end-va-start?view=msvc-172
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, lpFormatWCharArr);

    // does not include trailing NUL char
    const int cch = vswprintf(NULL,              // wchar_t *buffer
                              0,                 // size_t bufsz
                              lpFormatWCharArr,  // const wchar_t *format
                              ap);               // va_list vlist
    va_end(ap);

    if (cch < 0)
    {
        // handle error
    }

    const size_t NUL_CHAR_LEN = 1;
    const size_t buf_len = cch + NUL_CHAR_LEN;

    // malloc() is faster, but does not memset() result to zero
    wchar_t *buf = calloc(buf_len,           // size_t number
                          sizeof(wchar_t));  // size_t size
    if (NULL == buf)
    {
        // handle error
    }

    va_list ap2;
    va_start(ap2, lpFormatWCharArr);
    // does not include trailing NUL char
    const int cch2 = vswprintf(buf,               // wchar_t *buffer
                               buf_len,           // size_t bufsz
                               lpFormatWCharArr,  // const wchar_t *format
                               ap2);              // va_list vlist
    va_end(ap2);

    if (cch2 < 0)
    {
        // handle error
    }

    if (cch != cch2)
    {
        // handle error
    }

    // use 'buf' and 'buf_len'

    free(buf);
}
```

There might be a (code) typo in this answer, but similar code was tested against 64-bit Win 10.